# SSRS: Is there a way to hide the group toggle "+" button if there is no data to expand?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've created a report that groups rows together using multiple parent groups.

The issue I'm having is that most of the time, these groups will have several rows of data held within them. However, sometimes they have none. I've noticed that the "+" button will appear even if there is nothing to expand.

Is there a method or an expression to make that toggle only appear if there is data to show? I fell like this is something I'll get pulled up on when the report goes live, so I'd like to know if it's possible ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by 2 steps:

1. setting conditional visibility of a group (Group properties -> Visibility -> Show or hide based on an expression) and in the expression I would do CountDistinct of item which is under your group and if there is more than 1 item, hide it otherwise show it

```
=iif(CountDistinct(Fields!SUB_ITEM.Value,"GROUP") > 1, True, False
```

2. setting conditional InitialToogleState - go to group cell, search for InitialToogleState in properties, set when there is more than one item in countdistinct minus sign, otherwise plus sign

```
=iif(CountDistinct(Fields!SUB_ITEM.Value,"GROUP") > 1, False, True)
```

So by setting this you will have unrolled groups where there is no record and you will know that you don't have to click on them.

[image: result]

More reading about initial toogle states for example [here](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/12/21/visibility-settings-in-ssrs-drill-down-to-showhide-report-da.html).